# Android and arduino

Tags: java, android, arduino

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View led1on = findViewById(R.id.led_1on);
    View led1off = findViewById(R.id.led_1off);
    View led2on = findViewById(R.id.led_2on);
    View led2off = findViewById(R.id.led_2off);

    led1on.setOnClickListener(this);
    led1off.setOnClickListener(this);
    led2on.setOnClickListener(this);
    led2off.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void commandArduino(String url){
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

public void onClick(View thisView) {
    switch(thisView.getId()){
        case R.id.led_1on:
            commandArduino("http://192.168.0.15/?cmd=1");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_1on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.led_1off:
            commandArduino("http://192.168.0.15/?cmd=2");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_1off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.led_2on:
            commandArduino("http://192.168.0.15/?cmd=3");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_2on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.led_2off:
            commandArduino("http://192.168.0.15/?cmd=4");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "led_2off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

    }

}
}
```

I have this code but read that `httpclient` is not supported and now I must use `httpconnection`, so I read the documentation but I can't make it work.

Comment: Is there any error on your Logcat?

Comment: Error:(31, 13) error: cannot find symbol class HttpClient

Comment: Error:(31, 41) error: cannot find symbol class DefaultHttpClient

Comment: Error:(32, 36) error: cannot find symbol class HttpGet

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: It should be in your Question :)